# Flutter - Text is displayed outside it's container constraints

Tags: flutter

I have the following code that should display on pdf page two containers side by side, but they're overlapping, I displayed the container's borders and it is correctly created with width half of the page, but the text inside is still overlapping, I tried many different methods (Expanded, SizedBox, etc.) but I still have the same result.
FYI, pw is for PdfWidget the most used pdf library on pub.dev

```
pw.Padding(
        padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 30, right: 5),
        child: pw.Row(children: [
          pw.Container(
              decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                  border: pw.Border(
                left: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColor.fromHex('#EE2A2A')),
                right: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColor.fromHex('#EE2A2A')),
                top: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColor.fromHex('#EE2A2A')),
                bottom: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColor.fromHex('#EE2A2A')),
              )),
              constraints: pw.BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: pageFormat.availableWidth * 0.5,
              ),
              //width: pageFormat.availableWidth * 0.5,
              child: pw.Row(children: [
                pw.Container(
                    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                    alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                    child: pw.Text('Adresser à')),
                pw.Container(
                    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                    decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                        border: pw.Border(
                      left:
                          pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColor.fromHex('#EE2A2A')),
                    )),
                    child: pw.Column(children: [
                      pw.Text(
                        invoiceData.invoiceModel.customerName,
                        softWrap: true,
                        maxLines: 4,
                      ),
                      pw.Text(
                          invoiceData.invoiceModel.customerAddress
                              .printify(),
                          softWrap: true,
                          maxLines: 4),
                    ]))
              ])),
          pw.Container(
              constraints: pw.BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: pageFormat.availableWidth * 0.5,
              ),
              width: pageFormat.availableWidth * 0.5,
              child: pw.Column(children: [
                pw.Row(children: [
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                ]),
                pw.Row(children: [
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                ]),
                pw.Row(children: [
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                ]),
                pw.Row(children: [
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                ]),
                pw.Row(children: [
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                  pw.Column(
                    children: [pw.Text('Test')],
                  ),
                ]),
              ]))

        ]),
      )
```

And here's a screenshot of the result
[image: screenshot]